# К какому ip адресу подключаться к сайту через сокет

Tags: сервер, сокет

Здравствуйте.

1. На сервере создал сокет на php, который ждёт подключения.
2. Создал клиента на java на домашнем компе, который должен подключаться к сокету на моем сайте.

> Вопрос! Какой адрес ip использовать для подключения к сокету на сервере?

Когда я определяю ip адрес на java так 

`//host - имя сайта, например n.n.com
InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
String ip=ipAddress.getHostAddress();`
То **ip** сайта определяется не мой! А, например, так: 
Мой сайт **n.n.com**

Определяется так **s.s.s.com**

Как я определяю адрес на сервере
`$address=getHostByName(gethostname());`
Так определяется ip, такой же, как сказал хостинг. Если я использую этот адрес в java коде, то подключения не происходит.

> И ещё вопрос, какой адрес хоста использовать в коде на сервере, здесь 
> `$r = socket_bind($socket,'localhost', 12342);` вместо **localhost**.

> Почему я не могу перейти на сайт используя браузер. По указанному адресу с `getHostByName(gethostname());`?

**Вот код сервера**

```
printf('<br>start php...');


ignore_user_abort();


$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

$socketClients = array($socket);

if ($socket != false) {


$address = getHostByName(gethostname());

$result = socket_bind($socket, $address, 12342);

//много подключений на 1 прот
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

printf("socket_bind() error: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));

//не ждать если нету соединений, которые хотят подключиться
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

if ($result != false) {

    $result = socket_listen($socket, SOMAXCONN);

    if ($result != false) {

        printf('<br>wait connect...');


        $time = time();

        while (true and time() - $time < 20) {


            //проверка нового клиента
            $newSock = socket_accept($socket);

            if (is_resource($newSock)) {
                //новый клиент получен
                echo '<br>connect' . $newSock;

                $socketClients[] = $newSock;

            }

            /*
             //=========рпослушиванеи имеющихся
             $couchange=socket_select($socketClients, $efwfewfef, $efwfewfewwew, 0);
             if($couchange!==false){

             foreach($socketClients as $sock){

             //=====читаем з сокета
             while(strlen(socket_read($sock,1000))!=0){

             }

             //===пишем в сокет
             $err=socket_write($sock, "server php ".$sock);

             if($err===true){
             //оишбка

             }

             }

             }
             */
        }

    } else {
        echo '<br>нельзя прослушать';
    }

} else {
    echo '<br>нету бинда';
}

} else {
    echo '<br>not socket ';
}
```

**Вот код клиента**

`InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);`

```
        System.out.print("\nclient connect to ip:"+ipAddress.getHostAddress());
        Socket socket =new Socket(ipAddress, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Адрес хоста, должен соответствовать IP адресу машины, хостинга, или именно вашего  IP, но замечу почитайте про NAT маршрутизацию. Также, часто хостинги имею прокси, которые в итоге делают запрос к нужному адресу, так что лучше укажите именно IP вашего сайта, а не DNS имени.

Comment: Спасибо. Но если вы знаете больше, о проблеме подключения, которая может возникнуть - напишите, пожалуйста, здесь. Надеюсь это займет 30 секунд

Comment: А какая проблема подключения? О ней не написано в вопросе.

Comment: ок. не подключается. Если я использую на строне клиента айпи адрес сервера. прописанного в хостинге. На стороне сервера использую 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ну так в этом и есть проблема, 127.0.0.1 адрес локальной машины, почему вы не привязали глобальный Ip вашего сервера?

Comment: Глобальный уже пробовал, Это getHostByName(gethostname())

Comment: Надо поставить глобальный IP, не зарегистрированный порт, и обращаться к нему, через клиента.

Comment: Через клиента. А как иначе можно?

Comment: В панели управления хостингом нету такого, как глобальный ip. Есть IP Адрес Веб-сайта. Это, надеюсь, оно

Comment: Да, это то самое.

Comment: Ну так не коннектится, адрес биндится socket_bind возвращает true. И я правильно делаю так. Запускаю скрипт на сервере браузером, потом запускаю клиента на компе?

Comment: На сервере надо включить игнорирования отключения браузера, в PHP пропишите `ignore_user_abort();`

Comment: Нет. У меня и так браузер не отсоединяется. На php зациклено 20 секунд. Тоесть я постави и проверил ignore_user_abort(); - не помогает

Comment: Что именно в целом не получается? Как не происходит конект?

Comment: Тайм аут соединения на клиенте

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалкйста, исходные коды сервера и клиента

Answer (score 0):

Нужно слушать не на `localhost`, а на внешнем IP или на всех интерфейсах:

```
$r = socket_bind($socket,'0.0.0.0', 12342);
```

Только тогда, при условии отсутствия ограничений со стороны файрвола, кто-то из сети сможет подключиться к вашему сервису.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код сервера и клиента

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы.

**Проблема не подключения была в том, что хостер не позволял открывать порты.** Птому клиент не мог подключиться

Comment: Поди обычный shared-хостинг?